# What permissions should a udev rule have?

Tags: udev

What permissions should a udev rule have for a USB device? 644? 755?

For example on Ubuntu I'm looking at this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-lpcscrypt.rules`

Answer (score 6):

There's no reason to make a udev rule executable. They aren't executable (the kernel wouldn't do anything with them) and udev doesn't attach a special meaning to executable rule files.

A udev rule must not be writable to non-root user. A user who modifies it could inject arbitrary code that is run as root.

Udev rules don't normally contain anything confidential. Pretty much any information that's there can be revealed through `/sys` interfaces, `/dev` entries, `ps` calls while a `RUN` directive is running, etc.

So the right permissions are 644.